# i'm unable to understand how this code works

Tags: c, string

This is a c program to find out all possible combinations with a word -->

```
# include <stdio.h>

/* Function to swap values at two pointers */
void swap (char *x, char *y)
{
    char temp;
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

/* Function to print permutations of string
   This function takes three parameters:
   1. String
   2. Starting index of the string
   3. Ending index of the string. */
void permute(char *a, int i, int n)
{
   int j;
   if (i == n)
     printf("%s\n", a);
   else
   {
        for (j = i; j <= n; j++)
       {
          swap((a+i), (a+j));
          permute(a, i+1, n);
          swap((a+i), (a+j)); //backtrack
       }
   }
}

/* Driver program to test above functions */
int main()
{
   char a[] = "ABC"; 
   permute(a, 0, 2);
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

can anyone please explain me how the permutation code part is working? thanks in advance

Comment: For a small string like "ABC", you can work it out easily with pencil and paper.

Comment: Read about recursion, pointers and learn to use a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you have problem understanding the backtrack technique. In this case you should read a little about it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking

However the code works from the char at position 0 up to 2 following chars.
It changes the first char with the folowing, and calls itself with the next char as starting point. Finally switch back the chars to recreate the orign situation.

At the first level of recursion the function is switching the first letter and call itself for the next two:

```
permute("ABC", 1, 2)
permute("BAC", 1, 2)
permute("CBA", 1, 2)
```

second level of recursion:

```
permute("ABC", 2, 2) /* -> printf ABC */
permute("ACB", 2, 2) /* -> printf ACB */

permute("BAC", 2, 2) /* -> printf BAC */
permute("BCA", 2, 2) /* -> printf BCA */

permute("CBA", 2, 2) /* -> printf CBA */
permute("CAB", 2, 2) /* -> printf CAB */
```

Answer (score 1):

Take this code and run it, too lazy to write all the stages why not let the computer do it?

```
# include <stdio.h>

/* Function to swap values at two pointers */
void swap (char *x, char *y)
{
    char temp;
    printf("Swapping %c with %c\n",*x,*y); //<---------- I ADDED THIS FOR YOU
    temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

/* Function to print permutations of string
   This function takes three parameters:
   1. String
   2. Starting index of the string
   3. Ending index of the string. */
void permute(char *a, int i, int n)
{
   int j;
   printf("-----Now in permute(a,%d,%d)-----\n",i,n); //<---------- I ADDED THIS FOR YOU
   printf("-----String is now %s-----\n",a); //<---------- I ADDED THIS FOR YOU
   if (i == n)
     printf("%s\n", a);
   else
   {
        for (j = i; j <= n; j++)
       {
          swap((a+i), (a+j));
          permute(a, i+1, n);
          swap((a+i), (a+j)); //backtrack
       }
   }
}

/* Driver program to test above functions */
int main()
{
   char a[] = "ABC"; 
   permute(a, 0, 2);
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```